# Paperback novel: Earth hits cosmic string, human DNA affected, main character is a White Card - Protoman

Tags: story-identification

I read this in the late 80's early 90's as a long paperback novel. The earth hits a cosmic string, humans DNA is damaged. The main character is a "White Card" his DNA is pure. He is a slave/worker for someone who recognizes that he is a white card and is trying to make him into a "Protoman". He kills the guy and tangles his body in a fishing net to give the appearance that it was an accident. He escapes. The rest I don't remember much.

Comment: It was a long paperback novel

Answer (score 5):

It finally dawned on me that I hardly ever bought books randomly. They were either from one of my favorite SF authors or won a major award. So I looked through all the SF award winners for that time and found it.

*[Radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_%28novel%29)* - 1982 Nebula award winner